FFmpeg: The option 'to' works differently depending on where we put it. Why is it so?
Could anybody explain, why
ffmpeg -i input.mov -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:15 output1.mov

produces a 5-second video, from second 10 to second 15, whereas
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mov -to 00:00:15 output2.mov

produces a 15-second video, from second 10 to second 25?

man ffmpeg:

As a general rule, options are applied to the next specified file. Therefore, order is important, and you can have the same option on the command line multiple times. Each occurrence is then applied to the next input or output file.

So, -ss 00:00:10 before -i seeks the input to position 10s.
So, -ss 00:00:10 before the output skips the first ten seconds of the output, up to position 10s (not duration).
Your -to affects the output in both cases, and cancels on a position, not a duration.
